# custom module not detected

Tags: python, micropython

I'm currently new to python and I'm using micro python. I'm trying to use my custom module however, python can't seem to find it. The file is in the same directory. I've attached 2 images with the code. I don't see why it might not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3RQt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd2Uy.png)

Comment: maybe " from controller import * "

Answer (score 1):

Is `controller.py` in the same folder as `main.py`?

If `controller.py` is in another folder where your `main.py` is, you need to import it like this:

```py
import the_folder_has_this_file.controller
```

Comment: Yes, controller.py is in the same folder as main.py

Comment: can I see your work tree?

Comment: Make sure your modules are actually being uploaded and saved to the Pico's flash.  The IDE appears to be running the content of the editor, it may not be uploading and saving the files in the other tabs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72545880/importerror-no-module-named-sdcard

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialise your code as a package (e.g., have an `__init__.py` file in the same directory)?

If so you might need to locally install it with a `setup.py` file and the command `pip install -e .`